# Фон или картинку на картинку CSS

Tags: css, css3

Подскажите самый простой и кроссбраузерный вариант наложения фона или картинки на картинку. Нужно тупо затемнить.

Гуглил - но там черт ногу сломит. Нужно что-то простое, а предлагают и текст засунуть, и иконки, и кучу всего.

В идеале я бы сделал свой фон для наложения, но не знаю как впихнуть.

```html
<div>
<a data-title="title" data-lightbox="group-10" href="http://gdefon.org/_ph/8/1/478317672.jpg"><img class="" alt="alt" title="title" src="http://gdefon.org/_ph/8/1/478317672.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь для наглядности сделал градиент. Если вы не знали то в `css` можно перечислять свойства так `свойство: значение , значение2` т.е. через запятые. первое значение самое высокое, затем второе оно выше третьего и.т.д.

```css
.darker {
width:300px;
height:300px;
background:linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0), url(http://gdefon.org/_ph/8/1/478317672.jpg)
}
```

```html
<div class="darker">

</div>
```

Comment: А картинку на картинку так можно?

Comment: К сожалению свойства background-opacity пока нет но есть псевдоэлементы

Comment: @Duoxx Воу , этот вариант возьму для шапки. А можно как то натянуть фон на мою структуру `html` ? Я использую `lightbox` и мне этот эффект нужен при наведении , так как в `lightbox` такие эффекты отсутствуют , а для галереи одного pointer не достаточно.

Comment: Полностью натянуть?

Comment: @Duoxx не понял вопроса(

Comment: Натянуть в смысле чтобы затемнить а не наполовину?

Comment: @Duoxx Я не понимаю как мне затемнить при условии что мне нужно использовать lightbox. Там структура html немного другая и картинка не через background , а так как в моем примере.

Answer (score 5):

Для наложения картинок друг на друга нужно взять элементы и наложить их друг на друга (к примеру с помощью абсолютного позиционирования). Верхние элементы должны быть полупрозрачными.

Допустим есть 2 картинки:

[image: Природа 1]

[image: Природа 2]

Демонстрация:

```css
body {
  /* необязательные стили для демонстрации */
  margin: 0;
}

.image-overlapping {
  /* устанавливаем размеры контейнера */
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqIv7.jpg");
  /* делаем чтобы картинка полностью растягивалась, необязательный стиль */
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  /* позиционирование относительно контейнера */
  position: relative;
}

.image-overlapping:after {
  content: "";
  
  /* абсолютное позиционирование */
  position: absolute;
  /* растягиваем на всю ширину и высоту */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  /* добавляем полупрозрачность */
  opacity: 0.7;
  /* делаем чтобы полупрозрачный элемент располагался поверх основного блока */
  z-index: 1;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/bleHC.jpg");
  /* делаем чтобы картинка полностью растягивалась, необязательный стиль */
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-overlapping">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Контейнер сверху, а на него черный БГ, с прозрачностью неполной,

```html
opacity: .7;
```

Числа можно писать без нуля. 1-непрозрачный, 0 полностью прозрачный